# How to check the URL of a page using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, http, web, url

How would I make a script that detects the current URL of the page? Here is what I want it to do:

When the script is on example.com it lets the page load normally.

When the script is on coolsite.com it replaces the content of the page with a note showing a link to example.com

How would I do that? Is there a function that detects the location of the window? I can put it in a `<script>` element or a separate JavaScript file.

Thank you for any help!

Comment: _Is there a function that detects the location of the window?_ :: `window.location`

Answer (score -2, accepted):

```
window.location.host
```

It's not function just check that variable value

```js
document.body.innerHTML = `<h1>This JS runs under this host :</h1> <h2>${window.location.host}</h2>`
```

Comment: This so obviously should be marked as a dupe rather than answered. Keep SO clean!

Comment: Thank you so much! You are a livesaver! :)

Comment: Welcome @Echo !